# Android Studio Remove ActionBar

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I'm just looking for how I could remove the white bar at the top of the screen :(

[image: Interface]

**EDIT 1**

I've been looking for quite a while and hadn't taken the time to do a full question, so here's the code for the two files we're interested in.

I'm using a BottomNavigationBar so I removed the ToolBar because I don't need it. Problem is, it leaves space at the top of the shard set that I can't display anything in.

The style.xml code :

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.LearnCookingV2" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

And the activity code :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context=".ui.settings.SettingsFragment">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rellay1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/grad"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/imgUser"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_border">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivProfilePicture"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="120dp"
                    android:layout_margin="15dp"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/circle"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:src="@drawable/avatar"></ImageView>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvUserPseudo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/imgUser"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
                android:text="Pseudo"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="32sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linlay1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/followersBg"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvNbFollowers"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                        android:text="150"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="25sp"></TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvAbonnes"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                        android:text="Abonnés"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="25sp"></TextView>

                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/followingBg"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvNbFollow"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                        android:text="350"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="25sp"></TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvAbonnement"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                        android:text="Abonnements"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="25sp"></TextView>

                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linlay2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Nom"
                        android:textColor="@color/headings"
                        android:textSize="13sp"></TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvUserName"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                        android:text="Nom"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="18sp"></TextView>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Prénom"
                        android:textColor="@color/headings"
                        android:textSize="13sp"></TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvUserSurname"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                        android:text="Prénom"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="18sp"></TextView>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Email"
                        android:textColor="@color/headings"
                        android:textSize="13sp"></TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvUserEmail"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                        android:text="Email"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="18sp"></TextView>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Mot de passe"
                        android:textColor="@color/headings"
                        android:textSize="13sp"></TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvUserPassword"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                        android:text="Mot de passe"
                        android:inputType="textPassword"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="18sp"></TextView>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Age"
                        android:textColor="@color/headings"
                        android:textSize="13sp"></TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvUserAge"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                        android:text="Age"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="18sp"></TextView>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linlay3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/linlay2"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btModify"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/buttonsettings"
                        android:text="Modifier mon profil" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btLogout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/buttonsettings"
                        android:text="Deconnexion" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btDelete"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/buttonsettings"
                        android:text="Supprimer mon compte" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**EDIT 2**

I deleted the lines that referred to the ToolBar but now the application crashes because of this line in MainActivity :

```
NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController);
```

All MainActivity :

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_category, R.id.navigation_add, R.id.navigation_profile, R.id.navigation_settings).build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);
}
```

But if I remove that line then everything is fine but the problem persists.

Comment: Do you have any other fragments that use the action bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go to your styles.xml and change the app theme by replacing whatever actionBar style is provided by NoActionBar.

For example, look at how I have Theme.AppCompat.Light.**NoActionBar** below.

```xml
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.LearnCookingV2" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

And remove any line of code in your activity that has something to do with the toolbar. Including the line `NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController);`.
Because it is connecting/setting up the `navController` with the `actionBar` which is nothing but the toolbar.

Comment: The problem is that I am using a BottomNavigationBar and when I use your solution it crashes the application. In this case I may have done something wrong ?

Comment: Your question is fairly incomplete. How will the developers help you if you do not provide your code. In fact, if you do not provide code, then other developers might downvote your question saying it is not clear and detailed enough. Provide your code for styles.xml and your Activity.

Comment: So you said that you removed the toolbar. So how did you do that. Because that is the point the whole process of leaving the space begins. Tell me how did you do that.

Comment: I simply add this line "getSupportActionBar().hide();" in the MainActivity which manages the display of all the fragments. But I guess that's not really the right method.

Comment: That will simply hide it but won't remove it. Which keeps the space empty. Now remove any line code that has access with the toolbar. Such as the line above `getSupportActionBar().hide();` and then apply the answer I have mentioned above. That will solve it. And inform me if it works.